# how to add Serializable attribute on System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocket for convert to byte[]

Tags: websocket, attributes, addition

How can I add Serializable attribute on System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocket? 
I use this code:

```
System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocket ws = new ClientWebSocket();
TypeDescriptor.AddAttributes(ws, new SerializableAttribute());

var ss = ObjectToByteArray(ws); //Can not convert

ws = await context.WebSockets.AcceptWebSocketAsync();

public static byte[] ObjectToByteArray(Object obj) {

   BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();

   using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
   {
      bf.Serialize(ms, obj);
      return ms.ToArray();
   }
}
```

but does not work.

Error Code:

Type 'System.Net.WebSockets.ManagedWebSocket' in Assembly 'System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketProtocol,' is not marked as serializable.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do by serializing a websocket? There may be alternate ways of getting the same effect.

Comment: I have Asp.net Code layer And I have logic layer , and i can not use Socket List on Asp.net Code layer  from logic layer

Comment: how can i Access websocket class list from another project(layer)?